# Assigning a transfer value of a Football player given performance scores

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, prediction

I just recently landed my dream internship at a football statistics company and I am eager to impress. I have an excel spreadsheet of every player in the major leagues along with the minutes they played over the past 2 seasons, an attacking performance score and a defence measurement performance score (which is defence + possesion/2).

I have been tasked to assign a transfer value for all of these players but I have never done anything like this before so I'm not sure how to attempt it. So if anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated ! [An Example of how it is laid out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrXHk.png)

Comment: If you had information on transfer fee's you could do it using glmm and prediction. Take all of the players transferred in the last two* seasons and set the transfer fee as a response, and the other information as fixed effects... would give some idea at least where you can take any player pop in their info and it should spit out a predicted value, but it's very difficult because there are a lot of other factors (age, marketability [e.g. buying Chinese players will increase interest, and shirt sales, from a relatively untapped market], which club is making the offer... more and more)

Answer (score 1):

If that's *all* the data you have then you can't predict anything with any confidence.

If you also have data about previous transfers for those players, or players of similar ability levels, then you may be able to do something.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was thinking ! Maybe I should re phrase my question to assigning values to these players based on these given stats actually

Answer (score 1):

You can't just assign values to the players without any prior knowledge of the transfer values.

What you have to do is collect a dataset of player performance scores and their transfer values and fit a model to this dataset. With this learned model you can then predict the transfer values given the performance score.

Also have a look at [this paper](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/events/MLSA15/papers/mlsa15_submission_8.pdf)